# ‘readPrec’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Read’

Tags: haskell, ghc

The docs suggest `ReadPrec` is the more efficient representation for parsers than `ReadS` and say it is the one ghc uses to define derived `Read` instances. However, ghc gives the error that the method is not visible when I try to implement a `Read` with it.

```
instance Read PosTag where
   readPrec = mconcat . map posTagFromChar <$> lift (many (satisfy (`elem` "nva")))
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html

Comment: Have you tried `:t readPrec`? The result of that should be answer enough...

Comment: It is `readsPrec` (with an `s`), not `readPrec`.

Comment: `:t readPrec` -> var not in scope

Comment: `readsPrec` is the one using `ReadS`

Answer (score 6):

Apparently `readPrec` is not exported from `Prelude`... I had to import `Text.Read`. Thanks to leftaroundabout for the hint.